# como hacer visual studio code para que indique la etiqueta de apertura y cierre

Tags: visual-studio, visual

Tengo un problema al momento de dar click encima de una etiqueta ejemplo

me sombrea todas las etiquetas existentes.
Anteriormente tenia una extensión que al sombrear una me sombreaba la etiqueta de cierre, pero no logro encontrarla.

Existe algún otro modo?

agregue esta linea en la configuracion de visual studio code pero no funciono. "editor.matchBrackets": false debe quedar algo como:

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega lo que trataste o investigaste por favor, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: el codigo, que has intentado, [edit] tu pregunta y sube un [example]